How to make a search page accessible to all users having folder permissions?
I have a document library with several folders/subfolders/files.
Various users are assigned access at the doc librar's sub folder level.
I want to create a new search page and provide the above users access to the page. What is the simplest way to give the access?

The simplest way is put all users who can access the sub folder into a group, then grant this group with appropriate permission for the search page.
